Retrieve user’s mailbox items from Exchange Server 2019 On-Prem using Windows Authentication only (Direct from React or through .NET API)
Exchange Server 2019:
The requirement is to enable the user to open a webpage (mainly React JS) which will retrieve and display mailbox items for the current logged-in user by calling the /EWS/Exchange.asmx or any other service in Exchange Server 2019 On-Premises environment (not cloud-based).
Key Points:
1-  Connectivity: The client machines, backend servers (including MS Exchange Server), and the domain controller are all on the same network and domain, within an on-premises environment. (not cloud-based)
2-  Client: the user will log in to his/her windows machine (which is a domain joined machine) then the user will open the webpage from the browser, then the webpage will do one of the following approaches (Kindy check the diagrams):
a.  call the Exchange service directly by leveraging the profile of the logged-in user and display the inbox items, or
b.  call a windows-authenticated backend .Net API, the API will pick up the requester user’s profile then will call the Exchange service, and retrieve back the service response to the webpage
3-  Authentication: Inbox items retrieval should be using Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) (not by providing or storing any username / password) while invoking the service
4-  Deployment: If the backend .NET API approach is used (Apprach-2), the API will be deployed on a separate web server running IIS.
Note: I have tried lot of POCs and approaches, IWA didn't work with me at all
Diagrams:
Approach 1 : Webpage will call exchange service directly
Approach-1 diagram
Approach 2 : Webpage will call .Net API, which will call exchange service
Approach-2 diagram

First place to start would be to see what the authentication setting currently are on EWS virtual directory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/default-virtual-directory-settings?view=exchserver-2019 . If Windows Auth is enabled try using the Ewseditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases it allows you to try all the auth options. If it works with default creds then you just have a code problem which requires you to post the code and the errors you getting.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Thank you @GlenScales , i will try what you have recommended and get back to you.
